# Calculate row count when icons are used

Tags: excel, formulas

I have icon sets (Tick and close) used in excel rows. I need to calculate the count of "Ticks" in one cell and "close" in another cell. Can you please help me how to do that ?

For cells which has text i am using =CountIF(A8:A10):"Text" formula. but for icons im not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to use Excel cells only you will need to add another 'helper' column, which could be then hidden, that contains the conditional formula and then use count on that.

Alternatively you could open the Visual Basic editor and insert a module, using [this tutorial on conditional formatting](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/CFColors.htm)

Answer (score 1):

I think it can not be done using just functions. If you really need to see those icons for example and count them I would use something like 1 and 0 for counting, where 1 is tick and 0 close. If it bothers you, that there are 1 and 0 in cells then change font color to white, for example, then you wont see them, and to get those ticks and close icons use conditional formatting. Conditional formatting allows you to make icons, background color etc. [Here](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/06/05/excel-conditional-formatting-icon-sets-data-bars-color-scales/) is little documentation about conditional formatting. And to count use just =COUNTIF(A8:A10,"1") . That would be how I would do that, but I don't know what you are trying to achieve, hope this was useful.